# Run intermediate CA with TLS enabled: connection to root CA refused

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

So, I am trying to create a fabric network with a root CA, and several intermediate CAs, one for each org, everything with TLS enabled and self signed certs (no cryptogen). After running the root CA, I enroll the admin for it, and create affiliations and register identities for the intermediate CAs using the flag `hf.IntermediateCA=true`. Then I copy the tls-cert.pem from the root CA to the volume to be used by the intermediate CA, and then I try to start the intermediate CA issuing:

```
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -u https://<registered-identity>:<pw>@ca-root:7054 --tls.certfile /path/to/copied/tls-cert.pem
```

And I get the following answer:

```
[lots of things...]
Post https://ca-root:7054/enroll: dial tcp 10.111.83.239:7054: connect: connection refused
```

Without any clue about why the connection was refused. Checking the logs of the root CA looks like if nothing happened. Also I know it is not a connectivity problem (I'm on minikube and as can be seen in the logs, the DNS is being resolved correctly - double checked). I tried using env variables instead of the CLI flag, also tried using the flag `--intermediate.tls.certfiles` with the same certificate, and also tried the ca-root-cert.pem instead of the tls-cert.pem (which I think should also work), all with the same result.

Important to say that I've been able to start intermediate CAs without problem if I disable TLS everywhere, but I really need to enable this.

I am using fabric 1.4.2 images.

What am I missing? Thanks!

---

**Edit:** To answer @kekomal questions: I used both flags for TLS cert and enebled debug mode. Here's the complete Intermediate CA's log:

```
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Home directory: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [INFO] Configuration file location: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [INFO] Starting server in home directory: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Set log level:
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [INFO] Server Version: 1.4.2
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [INFO] Server Levels: &{Identity:2 Affiliation:1 Certificate:1 Credential:1 RAInfo:1 Nonce:1}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Making server filenames absolute
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Initializing default CA in directory /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Init CA with home /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server and config {Version:1.4.2 Cfg:{Identities:{PasswordAttempts:10 AllowRemove:false} Affiliations:{AllowRemove:false}} CA:{Name:ca-corp Keyfile: Certfile:ca-cert.pem Chainfile:ca-chain.pem} Signing:0xc000220870 CSR:{CN: Names:[{C:US ST:North Carolina L: O:Hyperledger OU:Fabric SerialNumber:}] Hosts:[0.0.0.0 ca-corp ca-corp.blockchain-alm-ns.svc localhost] KeyRequest:0xc00022cfe0 CA:0xc00022d060 SerialNumber:} Registry:{MaxEnrollments:-1 Identities:[{ Name:**** Pass:**** Type:client Affiliation: MaxEnrollments:0 Attrs:map[hf.Registrar.Roles:* hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles:* hf.Revoker:1 hf.IntermediateCA:1 hf.GenCRL:1 hf.Registrar.Attributes:* hf.AffiliationMgr:1]  }]} Affiliations:map[org1:[department1 department2] org2:[department1]] LDAP:{ Enabled:false URL:ldap://****:****@<host>:<port>/<base> UserFilter:(uid=%s) GroupFilter:(memberUid=%s) Attribute:{[uid member] [{ }] map[groups:[{ }]]} TLS:{false [] { }}  } DB:{ Type:sqlite3 Datasource:fabric-ca-server.db TLS:{false [] { }}  } CSP:0xc00022d100 Client:<nil> Intermediate:{ParentServer:{ URL:https://****:****@ca-root:7054 CAName:  } TLS:{Enabled:false CertFiles:[/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/tls-cert.pem] Client:{KeyFile: CertFile:}} Enrollment:{ Name: Secret:**** CAName: AttrReqs:[] Profile: Label: CSR:<nil> Type:x509  }} CRL:{Expiry:24h0m0s} Idemix:{IssuerPublicKeyfile: IssuerSecretKeyfile: RevocationPublicKeyfile: RevocationPrivateKeyfile: RHPoolSize:1000 NonceExpiration:15s NonceSweepInterval:15m}}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] CA Home Directory: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Checking configuration file version '1.4.2' against server version: '1.4.2'
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP: &{ProviderName:SW SwOpts:0xc0001d0500 PluginOpts:<nil>}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP with software options &{SecLevel:256 HashFamily:SHA2 Ephemeral:false FileKeystore:0xc00022f4b0 DummyKeystore:<nil> InmemKeystore:<nil>}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Initialize key material
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Making CA filenames absolute
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [WARNING] &{69 The specified CA certificate file /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/ca-cert.pem does not exist}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Getting CA cert; parent server URL is https://****:****@ca-root:7054
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Intermediate enrollment request: { Name: Secret:**** CAName: AttrReqs:[] Profile:ca Label: CSR:&{ [] [] <nil> 0xc00022d5a0 } Type:x509  }, CSR: &{CN: Names:[] Hosts:[] KeyRequest:<nil> CA:0xc00022d5a0 SerialNumber:}, CA: &{PathLength:0 PathLenZero:true Expiry:}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Enrolling { Name:ca-corp Secret:**** CAName: AttrReqs:[] Profile:ca Label: CSR:&{ [{US North Carolina  Hyperledger Fabric }] [0.0.0.0 ca-corp ca-corp.blockchain-alm-ns.svc localhost] 0xc00022cfe0 0xc00022d060 } Type:x509  }
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Initializing client with config: &{URL:https://ca-root:7054 MSPDir: TLS:{Enabled:true CertFiles:[/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/tls-cert.pem] Client:{KeyFile: CertFile:}} Enrollment:{ Name:ca-corp Secret:**** CAName: AttrReqs:[] Profile:ca Label: CSR:&{ [{US North Carolina  Hyperledger Fabric }] [0.0.0.0 ca-corp ca-corp.blockchain-alm-ns.svc localhost] 0xc00022cfe0 0xc00022d060 } Type:x509  } CSR:{CN: Names:[{C:US ST:North Carolina L: O:Hyperledger OU:Fabric SerialNumber:}] Hosts:[0.0.0.0 ca-corp ca-corp.blockchain-alm-ns.svc localhost] KeyRequest:0xc00022cfe0 CA:0xc00022d060 SerialNumber:} ID:{Name: Type: Secret: MaxEnrollments:0 Affiliation: Attributes:[] CAName:} Revoke:{Name: Serial: AKI: Reason: CAName: GenCRL:false} CAInfo:{CAName:} CAName: CSP:0xc00022d100 Debug:false LogLevel:}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP: &{ProviderName:SW SwOpts:0xc0001d0500 PluginOpts:<nil>}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Initializing BCCSP with software options &{SecLevel:256 HashFamily:SHA2 Ephemeral:false FileKeystore:0xc00022f4b0 DummyKeystore:<nil> InmemKeystore:<nil>}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [INFO] TLS Enabled
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] CA Files: [/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/tls-cert.pem]
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Client Cert File:
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Client Key File:
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Client TLS certificate and/or key file not provided
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] GenCSR &{CN: Names:[{C:US ST:North Carolina L: O:Hyperledger OU:Fabric SerialNumber:}] Hosts:[0.0.0.0 ca-corp ca-corp.blockchain-alm-ns.svc localhost] KeyRequest:0xc00022cfe0 CA:0xc00022d060 SerialNumber:}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [INFO] generating key: &{A:ecdsa S:256}
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] generate key from request: algo=ecdsa, size=256
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [INFO] encoded CSR
2019/10/25 08:22:56 [DEBUG] Sending request
POST https://ca-root:7054/enroll
{"hosts":["0.0.0.0","ca-corp","ca-corp.blockchain-alm-ns.svc","localhost"],"certificate_request":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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\nX3/4HvG8iw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n","profile":"ca","crl_override":"","label":"","NotBefore":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","NotAfter":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","CAName":""}
2019/10/25 08:22:57 [DEBUG] Closing server DBs
Error: POST failure of request: POST https://ca-root:7054/enroll
{"hosts":["0.0.0.0","ca-corp","ca-corp.blockchain-alm-ns.svc","localhost"],"certificate_request":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\nMIIBgzCCASoCAQAwXzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAgTDk5vcnRoIENhcm9s\naW5hMRQwEgYDVQQKEwtIeXBlcmxlZGdlcjEPMA0GA1UECxMGRmFicmljMRAwDgYD\nVQQDEwdjYS1jb3JwMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEws3abjcupN/X\nVa53vjv9Cdv1oVT/fDF4wNLGrNs6gMazFKN+0FCBQIywQxbdqszAxwl0Wh1yYzm5\np4E17FPPnqBpMGcGCSqGSIb3DQEJDjFaMFgwQgYDVR0RBDswOYIHY2EtY29ycIId\nY2EtY29ycC5ibG9ja2NoYWluLWFsbS1ucy5zdmOCCWxvY2FsaG9zdIcEAAAAADAS\nBgNVHRMBAf8ECDAGAQH/AgEAMAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0cAMEQCIHvXuMelMU9gVgWu\nb0tURDxJ/W5yvwikVEiMjAFma9tpAiBl3YQ1pbcNH53QAhn/4TjLaQLKeVDrK4a9\nX3/4HvG8iw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n","profile":"ca","crl_override":"","label":"","NotBefore":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","NotAfter":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","CAName":""}: Post https://ca-root:7054/enroll: dial tcp 10.110.28.98:7054: connect: connection refused
```

And the logs from the CA root:

```
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] DB: Getting identity admin
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Successful token authentication of 'admin'
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Received registration request from admin: { Name:ca-corp Type:client Secret:**** MaxEnrollments:0 Affiliation: Attributes:[{hf.IntermediateCA true false}] CAName:  }
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] No affiliation provided in registration request, will default to using registrar's affiliation of ''
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] canRegister - Check to see if user 'admin' can register
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Checking to see if caller 'admin' can act on type 'client'
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Checking to see if caller 'admin' is a registrar
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Validating affiliation:
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Checking to see if affiliation '' contains caller's affiliation ''
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Caller has root affiliation
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Checking to see if registrar can register the requested attributes: [{Name:hf.IntermediateCA Value:true ECert:false}]
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Validating that registrar with the following values for hf.Registrar.Attributes '*' is authorized to register the requested attribute '&{Name:hf.IntermediateCA Value:true ECert:false}'
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Checking if registrar can register attribute: hf.IntermediateCA
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Performing authorization check...
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Checking if caller is authorized to register attribute 'hf.IntermediateCA' with the requested value of 'true'
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Requested attribute type is boolean
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Registering user id: ca-corp
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Max enrollment value verification - User specified max enrollment: 0, CA max enrollment: -1
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] DB: Getting identity ca-corp
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] DB: Add identity ca-corp
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [DEBUG] Successfully added identity ca-corp to the database
2019/10/25 08:18:21 [INFO] 127.0.0.1:34862 POST /register 201 0 "OK"
2019/10/25 08:30:30 [DEBUG] Cleaning up expired nonces for CA 'ca-root'
```

Where you can see the previous process of registering the identity that should be enrolled when starting the intermediate CA. But does not show anything for the enrolling process (the refused connection).

Regarding your comment: you say that I should also send `--tls.keyfile` while starting intermediate CA. I don't understand this... private key should always be kept by the owner (in this case the root CA), should I also copy it to intermediate CA's volume? why? does that make any sense?

---

**Edit 2:** Finally @kekomal's answer gave me the clue: adding information about the CN of the parent CA let me go further. The working command is:

```
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -u https://<registered-identity>:<pw>@ca-root:7054 --intermediate.parentserver.caname ca-root --tls.certfile /path/to/copied/tls-cert.pem
```

Where the new part is `--intermediate.parentserver.caname ca-root`. BUT... Issuing this command gave me a new error in the intermediate CA's log:

```
Error: Could not load TLS certificate with BCCSP: Could not find matching private key for SKI: Failed getting key for SKI [[167 199 194 85 105 166 191 99 62 19 149 57 140 61 6 182 134 104 105 223 132 142 13 221 99 68 170 0 45 246 28 17]]: Key with SKI a7c7c25569a6bf633e1395398c3d06b6866869df848e0ddd6344aa002df61c11 not found in /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore
```

As the error suggested, I copied the private key from the root CA to the intermediate CA inside /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore, and just after that, the intermediate CA finally started.

But why is it necessary to copy this PK from root to intermediate CA? I'm really confused as we are working with asymmetric cryptography. Is it a bug? or am I missing something important?

---

**Edit 3:** Ok, one more update on this: As suggested by @kekomal, I tried issuing the command without enabling tls in the intermediate CA. So I stopped the network, deleted persistence for intermediate CA, and issued the command as suggested. To my surprise, the result was again a `connection refused` message. Then I tried again all the variations of `fabric-ca-server start` with no luck (same connection refused message). Finally I realized that the last time it worked, I issued first a fabric-ca-server start without params (to start it as a stand alone server), stopped it, and then sent the command with params. So, what I have done this time is to send first a `fabric-ca-server init -b admin:adminpw`, and then send the `fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -u https://ca-corp:NdckmlUAhTUP@ca-root:7054 --tls.enabled  --intermediate.parentserver.caname ca-root --intermediate.tls.certfiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/tls-cert.pem` (yes, with --tls.enabled, because I want the entire CAs network to work with tls enabled, not just the root CA), and yes!, intermediate CA is now working, and yes!, there was no need to copy the root CA's PK. My conclussion is that even when fabric documentation states that starting without running init before will implicitly run init, something is not working fine there, and **init must be called before start** for things to work fine, at least when TLS is enabled.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The default dockerhub fabric-ca image does that `init` on first run if you don't override the commands. I usually run my Fabric-CA on a docker container without overriding any command, just importing a suitable `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` and/or setting environment variables.

Comment: If you are using fabric-ca docker image, import a `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` and/or set environment variables with the equivalent to your command parameters without overriding any command. Both `fabric-ca-server init` and `fabric-ca-server start` will use parameters from configuration. If you simply override the `command`, `init` is executed on first run without taking your user and password.

Comment: Not using docker directly, but kubernetes, so a bit of handicraft with configurations. But it's a good idea to base everything on default config files whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm... The parent root CA TLS certificate (the trusted root certificates) should be specified with `--intermediate.tls.certfiles`. `--tls.certfile` and `--tls.keyfile` define the intermediate CA TLS certificate and key respect to its children/clients.

Set `--loglevel debug` to get more information (and share it).

---

**Edit:** To answer to your edition (I have no reputation to comment your post), when you talk about `--tls.keyfile`. I don't mean that you must use it. I mean that, if you use `--tls.certfile`, you must also use `--tls.keyfile`, as they are intended to serve your intermediate CA services via TLS, not to trust your parent root CA's TLS certificate. For your purpose, you have `--intermediate.tls.certfiles`.
Your command should look like:

```
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -u https://<registered-identity>:<pw>@ca-root:7054 --intermediate.parentserver.caname ca-root --intermediate.tls.certfiles /path/to/copied/tls-cert.pem
```

Possible errors I can think of:

1. `ca-root` does not point to your root CA.
2. Some firewall rule or similar blocks your request.
3. Your intermediate CA's port clashes with your root CA's port.
4. /path/to/copied/tls-cert.pem is not your root CA's certificate.
5. Neither of the CN or SANs of your root CA's TLS certificate matches the domain `ca-root`.
6. Your root CA's configuration enforces client/mutual authentication during TLS handshake and your intermediate certificate is not using it.

If you say that it worked when the root CA did not use TLS, and you have not broken any other thing during your changes, it can be one of 4-6...

Comment: Thanks for your replay @kekomal. I edited my question to add more information as requested.

Comment: Thanks very much @kekomal. I am sure that it has nothing to be with points 1-3 and 6. Will check points 4 and 5. Will update soon. Good list to take into account in general :)

Comment: Ok: Point 5 gave me the clue. @kekomal, please check an update in my question. I marked it as the right answer but it might be incomplete.

Comment: Don't copy the private key from the root CA in the intermediate CA. Just use --intermediate.tls.certfiles instead of --tls.certfile like I explained before.

Comment: Nope. Issuing `fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -u https://ca-corp:NdckmlUAhTUP@ca-root:7054 --tls.enabled --intermediate.parentserver.caname ca-root --intermediate.tls.certfiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/tls-cert.pem` after deleting the PK from the intermediate CA volume, gives me the same error: `Error: Could not load TLS certificate with BCCSP: Could not find matching private key for SKI: Failed getting key for SKI [[...]]: Key with SKI a7c7...1c11 not found in /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/msp/keystore`

Comment: Because `--tls.enabled` means that you want to serve your intermediate CA services via TLS and then it needs the private key. But that's not want you want (in this moment, at least). You don't want to use TLS in your intermediate CA. You want to connect your intermediate CA with a root CA that requires TLS. Please, try my suggested command without adding parameters of your own crop: `fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -u https://ca-corp:NdckmlUAhTUP@ca-root:7054 --intermediate.parentserver.caname ca-root --intermediate.tls.certfiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/tls-cert.pem`

Comment: Edited my question to add more information. Looks like **init** is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The TLS of rootca- cert.pem Copy directly to the folder of the corresponding organization. When the corresponding organization starts, TLS with the same name will be generated because TLS link is also started- cert.pem File, but it does not cover the TLS copied from rootca- cert.pem Documents. When organizations restart, TLS of the root CA are actually used- cert.pem Therefore, an error will be reported that the private key does not match the certificate

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's not possible to understand what you mean.